# How to check if the row of the first column is greater than the second in sql (Using IF Statement)

Tags: sql, ssms-2017

I wrote a query to create a table with one column

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER( 
   Order_Date DATE NOT NULL
)
```

I inserted two values into the column

```
--Order_Date--
2018-05-21
2018-01-21
```

How to check if the first row is greater or less than the second row using IF statement?

Comment: to compare using `if` you should store the values in variables and compare like this `IF @firstDate > @secondDate`

Comment: how can I get the value of each row, pls can you tell me? I don't know how to do that in a trigger

Comment: are you trying to do it in a trigger? it won't be impossible to know the last two or three inserted records, you can know only the last. I sugest you to include a identity column in order to use `order by` clause to get the last inserted rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "first" row or "second" row in a table.

You can do what you want if you include an identity column:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS ( 
   OrderId IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
   Order_Date DATE NOT NULL
);
```

Now, you can see if `OrderId` and `OrderDate` are in the same order.  Something like:

```
select (case when max(case when seqnum = 1 then order_date end) >
                  max(case when seqnum = 2 then order_date end)
             then 'greater than'
             when max(case when seqnum = 1 then order_date end) =
                  max(case when seqnum = 2 then order_date end)
             then 'equal'
             when max(case when seqnum = 1 then order_date end) <
                  max(case when seqnum = 2 then order_date end)
             then 'less than'
        end) as comparison
from (select o.*, row_number() over (order by OrderId) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o;
```

Notice that I also renamed the table to `Orders`.  `Order` is a really bad name for a table because it is a SQL keyword and a reserved word as well.

Comment: I tried your query on my laptop but is not working, pls can you show me the output of your query

Comment: My SSMS returned an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'". The problem might be because I don't know how to manipulate your query

Comment: @IsraelObanijesu . . . There should be a `case` in those expressions.

Comment: Your query is working but how can I use this to manage series of IDs. Is it possible for someone to check for the IDs in an automatic way without declaring it manually??

Comment: @IsraelObanijesu . . . As far as I can tell, this answer answers this question.  If you have another question, ask it as a question. Include sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.